# DNS Flag Day: what action is needed for edns512tcp=reset error?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Using the domain test at https://dnsflagday.net reports that our domains (hosted at several different DNS companies) all fail with this (note the `edns512tcp=reset`):

```
xxxxxxxxx.com. @98.124.243.3 (dns5.name-services.com.): dns=ok edns=ok edns1=ok edns@512=ok ednsopt=ok edns1opt=ok do=ok ednsflags=ok docookie=ok edns512tcp=reset optlist=ok,nsid (pdns12.dns.sjl.prod.tucows.net)

The Following Tests Failed

    EDNS - over TCP Response (edns@512tcp)

    dig +vc +nocookie +norec +noad +edns +dnssec +bufsize=512 dnskey zone @server
    expect: NOERROR
    expect: OPT record with version set to 0
    See RFC5966 and See RFC6891

Codes

    ok - test passed.
    nsid - NSID supported [RFC5001].
    reset - TCP connection reset.
```

But there are no actions explained by the site, and web searches are not making this any clearer.

It seems to be saying it doesn't expect `reset`? `dig` shows the domains all reply with the following, which is required:

```
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1452
```

What is the DNS flag day tester trying to tell me is wrong? And is there anything I can do to fix it, or is it a problem with our authoritative DNS host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify your domain name, but using the command specified in the output that you quoted I get the same "connection reset" behavior that they complain about:

```
$ dig +vc +nocookie +norec +noad +edns +dnssec +bufsize=512 dnskey example.com @98.124.243.3
;; communications error to 98.124.243.3#53: connection reset
$
```

As noted in your [ednscomp](https://ednscomp.isc.org/ednscomp) test output, what is expected in this particular test is:

```
expect: NOERROR
expect: OPT record with version set to 0
```

Ie, it expects a response with `NOERROR` status and an EDNS `OPT` pseudorecord with version `0` for this query.

The reported problem is specifically that your nameserver for whatever reason resets the connection instead of handling the query.

It is worth noting that the [ednscomp](https://ednscomp.isc.org/ednscomp) test suite includes many tests, what you find detailed in the output are the tests that failed. 
Ie, the dig command above is in itself by no means a comprehensive test, it just corresponds to a particular test scenario where your nameserver fails.

Comment: Interesting. I don't get the reset on my server using the exact command you used above. I get an answer ending with and OPT PSEUDOSECTION containing '; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1680'

Comment: Hmm. But I do get a timeout from 3 other servers, and now I do from mine when retrying a few minutes later. So I guess this is just a flaky server used by ednscomp?

Comment: @simpleuser It seems like `98.124.243.3` (maybe other servers from same provider as well) does not appear to work reliably over TCP, maybe even unrelated to EDNS options.

Comment: to clarify, when I wrote "I do get a timeout from 3 other servers" I meant I get a timeout when I run the dig command *from* multiple other servers, but using the same DNS @server in your command. thanks for your help!